# Dynamically Append UIComponent Tree using Xpage Markup

Tags: dynamic, xpages

I find myself writing way too much UI code to build up the component tree to support a custom control/library I'm building.

Is there a way to evaluate Xpage markup (i.e. Xpage markup fragment file), and append it to the component tree at run-time?

This would make it a lot easier as I could use designer to build the fragment, then copy/paste the fragment into a package resource in the control, load the fragment at run-time, evaluate it, cache it (maybe) and append the tree.

thanks

-Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the XPages Bazaar project on openntf.org. 
It enables you to create XPages on the fly.
http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20Bazaar

Comment: this was so close.  I got the plugin setup and got as far as the import of the xpage markup, but kept getting snagged on exceptions like "Complex type confirm must be added to a property".  I took a brief look at the project code but was unable to spot any obvious issues.  The offending markup was:

Comment: ran out of space.  when I have more time I'll review the interpreter code more thoroughly.  Would really be nice to have this fully functioning.  the interpreter didn't like the resources/dojoModules tags and this offending markup==>   <xp:link id="lnkDelete" text="delete">
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
<xp:this.action>
<xp:actionGroup>
<xp:confirm message="Delete?">
</xp:confirm>
<xp:executeScript script="#{backingBean.delete}">
</xp:executeScript>
</xp:actionGroup>
</xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:link>